# When you alternate a sculpting brush with modifier keys, is the alternation the exact same as the actual brush, or the inversion of the current brush?

Tags: sculpting, brushes

Since some brushes can be executed while using other brushes, via *modifier keys*, eg.:

- `Fill brush`, as I understand, is also accessible in `Scrape brush` by holding `CTR`.
- `Smooth brush`, as most of us know, can be accessed from most brushes, using `SHIFT`.

My question is ***how identical*** are those brush-alternation versions of the same brush, compared to the settings of the actual brush? Do they maintain all your current brush settings or do they inherit some default settings? If that makes sense.

I was particularly thinking about `Fill` as triggered by `CTR` while using `Scrape`, but I'm also keen to know the same for temporary-Smooth.

Comment: Just for the record, this question was a beast to formulate well.

Comment: The "shift version" of the *Smooth* brush has the same strength as the "normal" *Smooth* brush. So I think it's the same brush. The *Direction* (+/-) of the brush is also the same if you change it. You can switch the *Display Mode* of outliner to *Blend File* and then you will see all available brushes in the blend file.

Comment: Thank you @Blunder, that was good advice. Also curious whether `Fill` and `Scrape+CTR` have the exact same functionality. I know one might say, "hey, if they feel the same, they are", but I'm not happy with that argument :-) I want to know, so I can trust that any brush settings I set in Fill will also reflect when inverting the Scrape and vice versa. I guess I'd like to know if there's a principle to this: if all 'inverted' brushes are the same as their actual brushes.